# Create a nested array JSON in Vue.js (using v-model )

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-component

I am new Vue.js, I am working invoice project using Vue.js.
I want out put like this, output:

```
{
    "invoiceFirstLevelCategory": [{
        "categoryname": "first1",
        "price": 30,
        "invoiceSecondLevelCategory": [{
            "categoryname": "first-1-2-1",
            "price": 22
        }, {
            "categoryname": "first-1-2-2",
            "price": 0,
            "invoiceThirdLevelCategory": [{
                "categoryname": "first-1-2-3-1",
                "price": 11
            }, {
                "categoryname": "first-1-2-3-2",
                "price": 11
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Check Mycode :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text">
        <button v-on:click="addsecond">add second</button>
        <template>
            <div v-for="pre_second in second">
                <input type="text" v-model="pre_second.categoryname">
                <input type="text" v-model="pre_second.price">
                <button v-on:click="add_thrid(second)">add thrid</button>
                <hr>
                <div v-for="thrid in second_sub">
                    <input type="text" v-model="thrid.categoryname">
                     <input type="text" v-model="thrid.price">
                     <button v-on:click="add_thrid(second)">add next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <pre>{{second|json}}</pre>
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                second: [],
                thrid: []
            },
            methods: {
                addthrid: function() {
                    this.thrid.push({
                        categoryname: '',
                        price: 0
                    });
                },
                addsecond: function() {
                    this.second.push({
                        categoryname: '',
                        price: 0
                    });
                },
                add_thrid: function(arr) {
                    if (arr.isArray) {
                        console.log("they have nested", arr);
                    }
                    var th = this.thrid.push({
                        categoryname: '',
                        price: 0
                    });
                    console.log(this.thrid);
                    this.push(th);
                }
            }
            //main
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code was wrong, but I tried it many way. I don't know where is my mistake and find the solution.

Comment: `Property or method "second_sub" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`. And please add where current code is behaving wrong and how you want it to be.

Comment: I want to output like above my json